# Creating PDf consisting of multiple Pages with itext 7

Tags: html, .net, api, pdf, itext7

i am using itext 7 to create a multi Pages PDf out of a Html file.

```
MemoryStream finalDocumenStream = new MemoryStream();
StampingProperties documentProperties = new StampingProperties();
documentProperties.UseAppendMode();
PdfDocument finalPDfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(finalDocumenStream),
documentProperties);
```

I am looping in an foreach over an array and call this method to create the document:

```
CustomTagWorkerFactory customTagWorkerFactory = new CustomTagWorkerFactory(page);
Document pDFdocument = HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(htmltext, new PdfWriter(stream), 
converterProperties);
```

I want to save the Documents to finalPdfDocumet

```
pDFdocument.GetPdfDocument().CopyPagesTo(1, 
pDFdocument.GetPdfDocument().GetNumberOfPages(), finalPDfDocument);
```

After foreach() iam returning the finalDocumenStream; I was expecting to get all the documents in here.
I want to return the Pdf Stream from my .Net Api Controller:
return File(pdfStream, "application/pdf");

I am not able to combine the streams of inside the iteration and return the documents to client.

What iam doing wrong? Any advises?
Thanks for your help?

Comment: First of all please be aware that `PdfDocument` instances created with a `PdfWriter` usually on one hand contain unfinished objects and on the other hand already have data written out to the `PdfWriter`. Thus, you cannot cleanly copy pages from them to other documents. Usually an exception is thrown that says so... Thus, to combine such documents, initially target them to a `MemoryStream`, close them when they are finished, and construct a new `PdfDocument` based on only a `PdfReader` initialized with that `MemoryStream`.

Comment: @mkl Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried folowing but get "PDF Header not found":  `pDFdocument.GetPdfDocument().CopyPagesTo(1, pDFdocument.GetPdfDocument().GetNumberOfPages(), finalPDfDocument);   pdfWriter.GetOutputStream().CopyTo(finalDocumenStream);
                finalPdfDocuments.Add( new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(finalDocumenStream)))`

Comment: Grabbing the `PdfWriter` output stream is not helpful as it does not contain anything complete before the writer's document has been closed. See my answer for a more detailed version of my comment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please be aware that `PdfDocument` instances created with a `PdfWriter` usually on one hand contain unfinished objects and on the other hand already have data written out to the PdfWriter. Thus, you cannot cleanly copy pages from them to other documents.

When you try to copy from then, usually even an exception is thrown that says so. Do you probably catch and ignore such exceptions?

Thus, to combine such documents, initially target them to a MemoryStream, close them when they are finished, and construct a new `PdfDocument` based on only a `PdfReader` initialized with that `MemoryStream`.

I.e.

```c#
PdfDocument fullDocument = new PdfDocument(...);
...
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
PdfDocument partialDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(ms));
[... add content to partialDoc ...]
partialDoc.Close();
partialDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(ms.ToArray()));
partialDoc.CopyPagesTo(1, partialDoc.GetNumberOfPages(), fullDocument);
partialDoc.Close();
...
fullDocument.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, really appreciate :-)